# Amazing conjecture about patterns in primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I apologize if this isn't the place for this.

While playing with Primes I have discovered a pattern that doesn't seem to be trivial or coincidence, and I have no explanation or understanding as to why this should be true, so I wanted to share it here to get you guys' thoughts on this.

(Sorry for not typing it)
[Link of the image explaining what I found, with example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NlOK.jpg)
[image]

This conjecture can be generalized for any natural number ≥ 2, say for m ≥ 2, choose any n and find first m^2 primes ≥n and arrange them in an n×n table, find the difference between diagonal sums, use the difference as n and repeat and ultimately you will arrive at a constant C. For m=2 C is 1, for 9 C is 24, for 10 C is 46. C may not exist for some m.

Comment: This is not so surprising. For large $n$ you just need a result that tells you that the next few primes after $n$ are not much larger than $n$ (the prime number theorem tells you something along these lines), so the number you compute in step 2 is pretty small - it would be enough to show it's less than, say, $\frac{n}{2}$ as long as $n \ge 100$ or something like that, and then the problem reduces to checking a finite number of cases.

Comment: $1$ is not considered as a prime.

Comment: I mean if we take 1 as prime by definition.

Comment: @Shahrukh then you have to reconcile your definition of primality with almost 100 years' worth of mathematics, because much of it is built on 1 not being prime (especially number theory)

Comment: @H.sapiensrex then lets call the sequence non composite numbers ≥1.

Comment: That doesn't change the definition of primality to include 1, though. There's no way around it: if you want to define 1 as a prime then you've got your work cut out for you in making sure your conjecture doesn't break number theory

Comment: The difference between consecutive large primes is much smaller than the primes. I have difficulties to understand the generalization however. That this procedure giving ever smaller entries arrives at $1$ is not what I would call a "pattern". It just shows that there primes are in some sense "dense" although they more and more thin out.

Comment: "non composite numbers ≥1." actually describes the positive integers which are prime or $1$ , since $1$ is neither prime nor composite. But it is much less confusing to speak of "the primes and $1$"